# keeping certain dates from list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, loops, dictionary

```
listOfdicts =  [{'end': 352, 'id': 'T2', 'start': 342, 'text': '3/4/1920', 'type': 'DATE'},
 {'end': 687, 'id': 'T3', 'start': 679, 'text': '1/1/1909', 'type': 'DATE'},
 {'end': 710, 'id': 'T11', 'start': 702, 'text': '5/1/2000', 'type': 'DATE'}]
```

I have a list of dictionaries as seen above. (this is a sample. My real data is ~700K).  My goal is to keep only the `'text': somedate` if the `'type':DATE` is less than the date `1950`

What I would like as a final output is a list of dics with the dates that are under `1950`

```
[{'end': 352, 'id': 'T2', 'start': 342, 'text': '3/4/1920', 'type': 'DATE'}, {'end': 687, 'id': 'T3', 'start': 679, 'text': '1/1/1909', 'type': 'DATE'}]
```

I have tried the following code

```
older_age =[]

for l in listOfdicts:
    if l['type'] == 'DATE':
        if l['text'] <= 1950:
            older_age.append(l)
```

But this doesn't work quite work. How do alter my code so I keep only only the dates that are under under `1950`?

Comment: please specify if you want to keep the fields that aren't a date. Or keep only dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `int(l["text"][-4:])` rather than `l["text"]`, to only take the last 4 digits (the year) and convert them to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter, and split your date string and get the year first and then compare with 1950:

```
older_age = list(filter(lambda x : x['type'] != 'DATE' or int(x['text'].split('/')[-1]) <= 1950, listOfdicts))

print(older_age)
```

Output:

```
[
 {'end': 352, 'id': 'T2', 'start': 342, 'text': '3/4/1920', 'type': 'DATE'},
 {'end': 687, 'id': 'T3', 'start': 679, 'text': '1/1/1909', 'type': 'DATE'}
]
```

--Or as @Jean-FrançoisFabre suggested, you can use a list comprehension:

```
older_age = [d for d in listOfdicts if d["type"] != "DATE" or int(d["text"].split("/")[-1]) <= 1950]
```

Comment: a listcomp is better than `filter` + lambda: `filtered = [d for d in listOfdicts if d["type"]!="DATE" or int(d["text"].split("/")[-1])<1950]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code ...

```
import datetime

listOfdicts =  [{'end': 352, 'id': 'T2', 'start': 342, 'text': '3/4/1920', 'type': 'DATE'},
 {'end': 687, 'id': 'T3', 'start': 679, 'text': '1/1/1909', 'type': 'DATE'},
 {'end': 710, 'id': 'T11', 'start': 702, 'text': '5/1/2000', 'type': 'DATE'}]

older_age = [old for old in listOfdicts if datetime.datetime.strptime(old['text'],"%m/%d/%Y") < datetime.datetime.strptime("1950", "%Y")]
```

and the output will be:

```
[{'end': 352, 'id': 'T2', 'start': 342, 'text': '3/4/1920', 'type': 'DATE'},
 {'end': 687, 'id': 'T3', 'start': 679, 'text': '1/1/1909', 'type': 'DATE'}]
```